# Python Redirect Output of command to Variable

Tags: python, subprocess

First off all, i know this Question was asked before, but its a special case for me, because as the title says i want to redirect the Output of a command to a variable in Python. I know i can use subrocess.popen, but the command i want to run is an array, so i have to use subrocess.call(). I alredy tried to conver the array to a String, but this doen't work for me, because the Command contains spaces. So i need to use subrocess.call() to run my command. But is there a way to get the output of subrocess.call()?

Comment: Since you have mentioned it's a special case, can you post the command you want to run?

Comment: I want to Code a Minecraft launcher using minecraft-launcher-lib. The reason why i created this question is, to show the log of the Game in a special window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.run()` to capture the output of a command:

```
import subprocess

command = ["echo", "Hello, World!"]

result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

output = result.stdout.strip()

print("Output:", output)
```

Comment: This will throw an error, In order to execute this command you have to add one more argument in the `run`, whic is `shell=True`.

`result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)`

Comment: @Elie Hacen, Works fine. Double Checked.

Comment: No need to use pipes, just set `capture_output=True` or use `subprocess.check_output()`

Comment: @ElieHacen `shell=True` is required, if you want to run this one Windows